# Prove the reciprocal squared sum inequality

Tags: inequality

$\left( \dfrac{a^{2}}{b}+\dfrac{b^{2}}{c}+\dfrac{c^{2}}{d}+\dfrac{d^{2}}{a}\right) ^{2}\geq \dfrac{\left( a^{4/3}+b^{4/3}+c^{4/3}+d^{4/3}\right) ^{3}}{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+d^{2}}$

My First attempt was to substitude it for Cauchy-Schwarz in engel Form

$\dfrac{a^{2}}{x}+\dfrac{b^{2}}{y}+\dfrac{c^{2}}{z}+\dfrac{d^{2}}{w}\geq \dfrac{\left( a+b+c+d\right) ^{2}}{x+y+z+w}$

But with not success because of squared term. Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The hint:

Use the Holder's inequality.

Indeed, $$\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{b}\right)^2\sum_{cyc}b^2\geq\left(\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[3]{\left(\frac{a^2}{b}\right)^2\cdot b^2}\right)^3=\left(\sum_{cyc}a^{\frac{4}{3}}\right)^3.$$
About Holder see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/holder-inequality/info

Comment: Cant think of any other hint! +1

Answer (score 0):

@OP Just to clarify, the other answer from Michael is using the holders inequality in the below form:i.e., $r = 2/3$ and $s = 1/3$ and $x_k = a^2/b$, $y_k = b^2$,. To prove below inequality, from the general holders inequality we use,
$p = \frac{r+s}{r}$ and $q = \frac{r+s}{s}$ in holder's inequality,

[image]

Took this picture from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality